# java_sdk_1.8.0_openjdk - Fedora 35 and Mint

Tags: fedora, linux-mint

Where and how can I download java jdk 1.8.0 openjdk on Fedora 34 and Mint, please?

Answer (score 1):

Fedora

```
sudo dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
```

Linux Mint

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```